# Getting heap crash exception in 64bit .net-core where as 32bit is working

Tags: .net-core

Recently I am getting windows app crash issue while calling a native C++ functions from C++/CLI. This error occurs 80% of time whereas 20% no issues. This issue occurs only in X64 bit whereas in 32bit no issues at all. I can see few args are reset to NULL across call stack and believe this is .net-core issue?. Could anyone help to identify the root cause/resolve this issue?

```
ntdll.dll!RtlReportFatalFailure()  + 0x9 bytes  
ntdll.dll!RtlReportCriticalFailure()  + 0x97 bytes  
ntdll.dll!RtlpHeapHandleError()  + 0x12 bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlpHpHeapHandleError()  + 0x7a bytes 
ntdll.dll!RtlpLogHeapFailure()  + 0x45 bytes    
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal()  + 0x81db2 bytes   
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap()  + 0x51 bytes   
clrjit.dll!Compiler::lvaInitTypeRef()  Line 262 C++
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ * classPtr=0x00000000ffffffff, ICorJitInfo * compHnd=0x0000000000000000, CORINFO_METHOD_INFO * methodInfo=0x0000000000000000, void * * methodCodePtr=0x00000079073f80e0, unsigned long * methodCodeSize=0x00000079073f8414, JitFlags * compileFlags=0x00000079073f80d8, CorInfoInstantiationVerification instVerInfo=0xa1e332a1)  Line 6161   C++


clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ * methodHnd=0x00007ff921b4ae30, CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ * classPtr=0x00007ff921b421e0, ICorJitInfo * compHnd=0x0000000000000000, CORINFO_METHOD_INFO * methodInfo=0x00000079073f84f0, void * * methodCodePtr=0x00000079073f80e0, unsigned long * methodCodeSize=0x00000079073f8414, JitFlags * compileFlags=0x00000079073f80d8)  Line 5644 + 0x1a bytes  C++


clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(CORINFO_METHOD_STRUCT_ * methodHnd=0x00007ff921b4ae30, CORINFO_MODULE_STRUCT_ * classPtr=0x00007ff921b421e0, ICorJitInfo * compHnd=0x00000079073f8300, CORINFO_METHOD_INFO * methodInfo=0x00000079073f84f0, void * * methodCodePtr=0x00000079073f80e0, unsigned long * methodCodeSize=0x00000079073f8414, JitFlags * compileFlags=0x00000079073f80d8, void * inlineInfoPtr=0x0000000000000000)  Line 6953 + 0x50 bytes C++
```

> clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(ICorJitInfo * compHnd=0x00000079073f81c0, CORINFO_METHOD_INFO * methodInfo=0x00000079073f8300, unsigned int flags=0x789ddc80, unsigned char * * entryAddress=0x00000079073f82f8, unsigned long * nativeSizeOfCode=0x00000079073f8414)  Line 312    C++

I tried with 32 bit compilation and it is working 100%. But we need to provide 64bit since app may use more than 4GB RAM.
Created core dump and analyzed, but found that the issue is from .net-core.
Application environment is VS 2019 with std:c++14 / .net4.6

Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.2130, time stamp: 0xb5ced1c6
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ff6a9

Comment: The exception isn't caused by jitNativeMethod(), it is merely the victim of the heap corruption.  Use Application Verifier or a code review to find the cause.